# Anonymous users creating content types: which approaches instead of invokeFactory can be used?

Tags: plone

I've come across [this little function](http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Anonymous-Publishing-Proxy-Roles-and-CMFFormController-tt305654.html#a305655) that let anonymous users call invoke factory.

```
security.declarePrivate('anonymousInvokeFactory') 
def anonymousInvokeFactory(self, container, type_name, id, 
    REQUEST=None, *args, **kw): 
    """ 
    Anonymous cannot add objects with InvokeFactory, so this is a 
    special 
    method to do it with. Must be called from other function to limit 
    possibillities of abuse. 
    """ 
    # remember original user 
    mtool = getToolByName(self, 'portal_membership') 
    originalUser = mtool.getAuthenticatedMember() 
    # wrap the request in new security to be able to add content 
    user = self.getWrappedOwner() 
    newSecurityManager(REQUEST, user) 
    container.invokeFactory(type_name, id, REQUEST=REQUEST, *args, **kw) 
    # set original user again 
    newSecurityManager(REQUEST, originalUser) 
    return id
```

I seems perfect for a situation where I'm using some proxyManager metadata. But I haven't seen this little snippet anywhere besides this nabble entry - is it safe? Which disadvantages can you see in this approach? **EDIT**: I've found now in [official community plone docs effort](http://collective-docs.plone.org/security/permissions.html#id8) some references.

My scenario: the anonymous user is creating an Archetype object on ZODB, in a specific context only, that only accepts this type of object. He can not see any objects, he is just calling a form that is going to create these objects. These objects are going to be created, and their attributes (fields) need to be populated as well. The `_createObjectType` approach creates the object but it doesn't add the fields even using `**kwargs`. **EDIT2**: It's possible to edit using default acessors like `obj.setTitle`. I'm now using this approach, and it works flawlessly.

Comment: The side-effects depend on how you're planning to use it. I'm sure you don't just want to allow any user to create content anywhere... Maybe a example use case for this would help others understand what the risks are and help you to implement it better.

Comment: @vangheem: The user is not going to create content anywhere, just in a specific context. I'm looking for risks using newSecurityManager in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be weary of using anything that sets up a new security manager. A better way to do this would be to bypass security when creating the object.

You can do something like:

```
        pt = getToolByName(context, 'portal_types')
        type_info = pt.getTypeInfo('portal_type')
        ob = type_info._constructInstance(context, id)
        # CMFCore compatibility
        if hasattr(type_info, '_finishConstruction'):
            return type_info._finishConstruction(ob)
        else:
            return ob
```

source: [uwosh.pfg.d2c](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/uwosh.pfg.d2c/trunk/uwosh/pfg/d2c/content/savedataadapter.py)

Comment: Searching for "bypass security when creating the object" get me to this: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/content/creating#bypassing-permissions-when-creating-content-item These seems to be a *much* simples solution. What do you think? (And thanks for the hint, I haven't thought about just searching for "bypass security" :P)

Comment: Yah, that's pretty much the same as what I put here. The only difference is in certain versions of Plone you need to also issue the _finishConstruction method.

Comment: I've done some grep to read `_createObjectByType`, and it returns `return fti._finishConstruction(ob)` already. In Plone 4, I've seen that _finishConstruction is not needed anymore. If I call _finishConstruction like in your example in a Plone 4, is it going to throw an error?

Comment: I can create the content types, but can't edit their properties. This is useless. According to the docs in the link I provided, "The function above only bypasses the content item contruction permission check. It does not bypass checks for setting field values for initially created content.". So, I'm afraid I still need to use my approach.

Comment: Hum, I can use `obj.setTitle` and such to edit the fields, after using `_createObjectType`. This should be at the documentation...

Comment: _constructInstance and _finishConstruction both return instances of the object where you can cal "setTitle" and such.